# Change frame color of CEdit when Focus

Tags: c++, mfc

with following code, my Edit boxes do get a red colored frame and a yellow background, whenever they obtain focus. However, when I enter text, the text is unvisible at first, I have to hover with my curser to another dialogitem to see the text i just entered. Whyt do I have to change to see the text withput moving my mouse?

```
HBRUSH CDialog23::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC || nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_DLG)
    {
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
        hbr = m_Weiss;
        return hbr;
    }
    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_LISTBOX)
    {
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 230, 153));
        hbr = m_Gelb;
        return hbr;
    }
    const CWnd* focusWnd = GetParent() ? GetParent()->GetFocus() : nullptr;
    bool hasFocus = focusWnd && focusWnd->GetSafeHwnd() == pWnd->GetSafeHwnd();
    if (hasFocus)
    {
        if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == pWnd->GetFocus()->GetDlgCtrlID() && nCtlColor != CTLCOLOR_STATIC)
        {
            pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
            pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 230, 153));

            CRect rect;
            pWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
            rect.OffsetRect(-rect.left, -rect.top);
            CBrush brush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
            pDC->FrameRect(&rect, &brush);
            ReleaseDC(pDC);
            
            hbr = m_Gelb;
            return hbr;
        }
        else
        {
            pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
            pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 255, 255));
            hbr = m_Weiss;
            return hbr;
        }
    }
    return hbr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I get the custom color on focus on `CEdit`:

```
HBRUSH CMyDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    // TODO: Change any attributes of the DC here

    switch(nCtlColor)
    {
    case CTLCOLOR_EDIT:
    case CTLCOLOR_MSGBOX:
        if(IDC_EDIT_HEX == pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID())
        {
            pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(210, 210, 240));
            hbr = static_cast<HBRUSH>(m_pBrush->GetSafeHandle());
        }
        break;
    }

    // TODO: Return a different brush if the default is not desired
    return hbr;
}
```

[image]

Does it help you ?

Answer (score 0):

Drop `ReleaseDC();`
You did not make a call to get DC, a pointer to a DC object was delivered to you by the caller. Releasing this DC is completely unnecessary.

An update:
Use MEMC (Minimum Coding Maximum Effect)
I did some more work and came up with the following solution:

- Derive a class from `CEdit`
- Handle reflection messages: `EN_SETFOCUS`, `EN_KILLFOCUS`, and `WM_CTLCOLOR`
- Paint the frame in `WM_NCPAINT` handler
  Declare member `boolean` variable to determine when focus changes should take place. I called it `m_DoChangeBacground`. the rest is below:

  ```
   void CEditChangeFocus::OnEnSetfocus()
   {
       m_DoChangeBacground = true;
   }


   void CEditChangeFocus::OnEnKillfocus()
   {
       m_DoChangeBacground = false;
   }


   HBRUSH CEditChangeFocus::CtlColor(CDC* pDC, UINT nCtlColor)
   {
       // just the sanity check while debugging
       ASSERT(CTLCOLOR_EDIT == nCtlColor);

       if(m_DoChangeBacground)
       {
           pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
           //pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 230, 153));

           return m_YellowBK;  // yellow brush

       }
       // TODO:  Return a non-NULL brush if the parent's handler should not be called
       return nullptr;
   }


   void CEditChangeFocus::OnNcPaint()
   {
       if(m_DoChangeBacground)
       {
           CRect rectWnd;
           GetWindowRect(&rectWnd);
           rectWnd.OffsetRect(-rectWnd.left - 2, -rectWnd.top - 2); // do painting in non client area
           CDC* pDC = GetDC();
           pDC->FrameRect(&rectWnd, &m_RedFrm);
           ReleaseDC(pDC);
       }
       else
       {
           CEdit::OnNcPaint();
       }
       // TODO: Add your message handler code here
       // Do not call CEdit::OnNcPaint() for painting messages
       // WRONG! do call it if not handled by your code
   }
  ```